# Date with Sept picked as null in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The application is in ASP.NET MVC 4 wherein in View there is TextBox attached to the jQuery DatePicker to select only Month and Year combo.

It is declared as:

```
@Html.TextBox("myDate", Model.myDate.HasValue ? Model.myDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty, new { @readonly = "readonly", maxlength = "12", style = "width: 75px;height:20px", id = "myDate" })
```

And the value is picked as:

```
$(function () {
    $("#myDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function () {
            var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
        },

        beforeShow: function () {
            if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),
                         $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The value in the textbox is sent to controller method via ajax call:

```
data: $("#myForm").serializeArray();
```

Here when the form Array is inspected before sending, the text contains value as "Sept 2019", "July 2019" etc.

In model the field i.e. myDate is defined as datatype DateTime? with no other attributes.

Issue is when I select Sept 2019 the underlying model on code-behind side gets null value.
Initially I thought it might be due to Sept has 4 characters but June 2019, July 2019 works fine.

I am not sure why only for values for myDate containing Sept are being null while it is working for other months.

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `$("#myForm").serializeArray()` to see what is being generated and sent to the server?

Comment: I tried to serialize with same setup as yours before using AJAX and get full-month `September 2019` instead of `Sept 2019`. Can you provide other related details?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I inpected the array. The key value pait contains name: myDate and Value: Sept 2019. So I assume jQuery is doing its part, I am not able to understand how .net is assigning values in the incoming array to the DatetTime filed in model.

Comment: As a side note you should be using `.serialize()` rather than .serializeArray()`. In order for the `DefaultModelBinder` to bind it, it needs to be the fill month name - `myDate: 'September 2019'`, (not `'Sept 2019'`)

Comment: Note tested but it should also work with `'Sep 2019'`

Comment: `Sep 2019` still works - because `MMM yyyy` format still acceptable. Not sure why `Sept 2019` used in place of `September 2019` - also `serializeArray()` is modifiable version of `serialize()`, not recommended if the form values are fixed ones.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, above mentioned code is everything. And it is giving me months like Jan, July, Sept etc. only.

Answer (score 1):

So finally found the answer. The .net framwork somehow was not able to convert Sept 2019 to a valid DateTime but running well when passing Sep 2019 or September 2019.
To counter that passed the monthNames array as an parameter to DatePicker to only have 3 letter month names as;

```
$(function () {
    $("#myDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        minDate: 0,
        monthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
        onClose: function () {
            var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
        },

        beforeShow: function () {
            if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),
                         $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This worked and now I can get valid DatetIme for Sept 2019